# webpack starting but not watching for changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a repo set up for a project which is using webpack and works perfectly. I copied the entire repo to start a new project. Now when I run "npm run watch" webpack starts but will not watch for changes. my package.json file looks like this:

```
    {
  "name": "donedone-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --colors"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.8",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "img-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

and my webpack config like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

require('webpack/lib/ResolverPlugin');



// const webRoot         = './site/'
// const assetsPath      = path.join(webRoot, 'assets')
// const srcDir          = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
// const srcAssetsPath   = path.join(srcDir, 'assets')
// const spritePath      = path.join(srcAssetsPath, 'sprites')

var config = {
  entry: './src/js/main',
  externals: {
    'jquery': '$'
  },
  output: {
    path: './site/assets',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.js?/,
        loader : 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
       },
     {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader: 'url?limit=25000!img?progressive=true'
     },
     {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader  : 'url?limit=90000'
      }
    ]
  },


   plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css', {
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

When i run "npm run watch" in terminal, webpack seems to begin normally just as it does with my working repo, except not looking for changes. Here is what it displays:

```
jordansykes  ~/sites/side-projects/mofilm
$ npm run watch

> donedone-api@1.0.0 watch /Users/jordansykes/Sites/side-projects/mofilm
> webpack --progress --colors --watch

Hash: f57ca91a3a54e729eb37
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 789ms
  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  1.45 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 1 hidden modules
```

Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Comment: webpack -w './src/js/main.js'

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is this what I need to change the entry to?

Comment: did u try change relative path to absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions. Because I copied the repo in finder, .babelrc file that doesnt show up in finder, was not copied over. When this was created again in the root, everything compiled correctly.